# javascript into php arrays

Tags: javascript, php

i have a problem thinking Javascript into PHP arrays.
I'm playing with the config of a flowplayerplugin for Drupal which allows me to config the player like this:

```
 flowplayer_add('#player', array(
          'playlist'=> array(array(
              "autoPlay" => TRUE,
              'cuePoints'=>array(
                array(
                 "name"=>"vpspot"
                )
              ),
              "url" => $videourl,
          )),        
      ));
```

What I need additionally in javascript is this:

```
      onLoad:  function()  {  // called when player has finished loading
          this.setVolume(0);  // set volume property
      }
```

Is there a way to integrate this into the php notation?

My try was this:

```
 flowplayer_add('#player', array(
          'onLoad'=> 'function(){this.setVolume(0);}',
          'playlist'=> array(array(
              "autoPlay" => TRUE,
              'cuePoints'=>array(
                array(
                 "name"=>"vpspot"
                )
              ),
              "url" => $videourl,
          )),
```

What php does is to set this in quotes. This errors in the browser

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: You can from php print JavaScript, to do the other you need to pass the data to PhP, with an ajax or with page change.

Comment: Did you succeed in making your first example work? What version of Drupal and the Flowplayer module are you using?

Comment: no not yet latest flowplayer module and drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

```
flowplayer_add('#player', array(
          'onLoad'=> 'function(){this.setVolume(0);}',
          'playlist'=> array(array(
              "autoPlay" => TRUE,
              'cuePoints'=>array(
                array(
                 "name"=>"vpspot"
                )
              ),
              "url" => '<?php echo $videourl; ?>',
          )),
```